# Will lock prevent the error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, deadlock

Here is my log writing function:

```
public static void WriteLog(string source, string message)
{
    string logFilePath = @"C:\LogFile\log.txt";
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logFilePath, true))
    {
        sw.Write(source + ": :" + message);
    }
}
```

But this code sometimes caused me the error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

So I modified my code a bit, and here is my new code:

```
public static void WriteLog(string source, string message)
{
    object _lock = new object();
    lock (_lock)
    {
        string logFilePath = @"C:\LogFile\log.txt";
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logFilePath, true))
        {
            sw.Write(source + ": :" + message);
        }
    }
}
```

Though I haven't received an error after using this code. But still I just wanted to know if this is correct way to use lock to prevent such errors due to deadlock, and if the way I have used lock is correct or not.

Comment: This is not a good idea - it will serialize access to the log from all the site users and can impact performance. Or rather, it would if you had a shared lock. Are you sure you did not have the file open in some application?

Comment: Oded is right. You'd better implement consumer/producer pattern with many producers and one consumer writing strings to file.

Comment: Please READ -- do not write code to "write log to file" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your use of lock in your second example won't work properly anyhow because you create a new lock object and lock it every time.

What you really want file wise is something like this:

```
public static void WriteLog(string source, string message)
    {
        string logFilePath = @"C:\LogFile\log.txt";

        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(logFilePath,FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None)) 
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);

            writer.write(source + ": : " + message);

            file.Flush();
            file.Close();
        }
    }
```

This should exclusively lock the file while you write BUT properly close off the file once done with.

This does NOT solve the threading issue, because two threads can still collide. If one thread locks the file subsequent requests will fail.

To solve this with a lock, move the lock object to a static that all threads can share and lock against, such as:

```
public static class Logger
{

    private static object locker = new object();

    public static void Log(string source, string message)
    {
        lock (locker) 
        {
            string logFilePath = @"C:\LogFile\log.txt";

            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(logFilePath,FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None)) 
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);

                writer.write(source + ": : " + message);   
                writer.Flush();

                file.Close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This will cause subsequent threads to wait until the lock becomes available before writing to the file as originally expected.

Note Oded's comment though, that still applies to this method.

Comment: Is this thread-safe? What will happen if several threads try to write log simultaneously?

Comment: Added a second thread-safe example, however Oded does make a point on performance depending on usage. Personally I go for a multi-write single read queue system that logs events to a queue a single thread writes out.

Comment: @Lloyd in this case if suppose a thread is using a file and another thread tries to write to the same file will it throw an error or just wait without throwing any error, and write to the file wen available

Comment: @Lloyd and will writer get disposed off automatically

Comment: With a lock it will wait until available. Writer will be GC'd but you can wrap with a further using() if you want to.

Comment: everytime I read questions regarding locks and IO with threading considerations.. I think.. what does `System.IO.File.ReadAsync` do and how have these logging frameworks handled it.. here's a consideration to that [FileAppender - log4net](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4net/trunk/src/Appender/FileAppender.cs). the locking strategies being the relevant portions..

Answer (score 3):

Use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi) or the [Logging Application Block in Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx). It would sure help you since they already have buffered writing to file.

You can find plenty samples on the Internet.